# Why is Eclipse Android failing to load some bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a working app, a simple snakes game. It works (or rather, worked). I want to clean up the bitmaps prior to release. However, now Android has decided it can't load 3 bitmaps despite them being present in the folder and under Eclipse's resources. Huh??

```
        src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snake_crash_down, opts);
        bm_crash_down = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, tileSize, tileSize, true);
        src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snake_crash_up, opts);
        bm_crash_up = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, tileSize, tileSize, true);
        src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snake_crash_left, opts);
        bm_crash_left = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, tileSize, tileSize, true);
        src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snake_crash_right, opts);
        bm_crash_right = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, tileSize, tileSize, true);
```

The first bitmap here, crash_down, loads just fine, as do the two dozen bitmaps before it, but the other three bitmaps won't load. R.drawable.snake_crash_up exists. The file exists. Eclipse finds it. Eclipse can open it. But Android returns a null pointer when I try to load it with BitmapFactory. This file is *unchanged* from when this app was working an hour ago! All I've done is add a couple of other graphics. I've tried 'Project > Clean...' and that doesn't fix it. What's wrong?

Renaming the bitmaps doesn't work. Replacing the graphic with a working bitmap (crash_down) and renaming them doesn't work.

Comment: What's the DPI of the Android system you test on, and do you have these 3 images either in the corresponding drawable folder or in the default drawable folder?

Comment: Two different devices (220 and 320 dpi). But the graphics themselves are only in the xlarge-xhdpi folder. I have one copy and scale them manually for different devices, disabling Android's native scaling. That's where the crash_down graphic is which works, where the other graphics don't despite being in the same folder.

Comment: How about moving them into drawable-nodpi, since that's where images you don't want Android to scale usually go to.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved by placing low-res copies in the Drawable folder. Kai was pretty much right although I discovered it myself before reading his post, although the 'nopdi' seems unnecessary (I think I'm using scaled bitmaps for some screen resolutions, and not for others. It's an old codebase!).

The take home point of this answer for anyone who reads it is that Android has a particular way of working that you have to understand and follow. A hodge-podge solution as I've used may work, but then it may randomly break and give you no clues as to why, and all sense and reason cannot track down the bug. If you find yourself experiencing random breaks of things that worked, check that you are following the Book of Droid to the letter!